# Why isn't $r^{\frac{n}{2}}$ classified as an involution?

Tags: definition, dihedral-groups

Suppose you have a $(2n)$-gon for some $n \in \mathbb{N} : n > 1$. Then the rotation $r^{\frac{n}{2}}$ where $n$ is the number of vertices imposed on the $(2n)$-gon is the same as an involution.

By same, I don't really know what I mean. It gives the same result, but the function isn't the same. Is it possible to define it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Write down the matrix of $r$ as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\theta = 2\pi/2n = \pi/n$. Now what happens when you raise to the power $n/2$?

Comment: I don't really see what this has to do with the question.